# Diagrama de flujo CodeForces 282A y 546A

Tags: diagrama-de-flujo

estoy necesitando ayuda medianamente urgente y lo que pasa es que necesito hacer un diagrama de flujo con respecto a dos problemas de CodeForces y no me ha sido posible realizarlo, adjunto el link de cada uno.

285A: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/282/A

546A: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/546/A

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué haces hecho? ¿Cuál es tu problema?

Comment: Aqui no te hacemos las tareas.